# distance calculations splitting highways km, toll ways km, and other roads km

Tags: google-maps, road, distance-matrix

Till now I have been able to use  MapPoint  or  Google Maps for a lot of things, specially directions and road trips distance calculations.

Today I need again to perform (massive) road trips distance calculations.
But I also need to split each distances in three components:

1. highway km
2. toll roads km
3. other roads km
4. total distance = 1 + 2 + 3

I could not see how to get these information from the MapPoint API or from the Google Map API.
The directions that I could get from them seem unsuitable to identify  highways  or  toll roads.

Would you know how I could solve my problem?
I have at least 50000 distances to calculate.
My preference would go to using Google Maps.
But I could use any other system as long as it is for free or very cheap.

Answer (score 1):

I finally could do the jobwith BingMaps using REST.
The returned directions contain road and country indentifiers that I could combine with a file of toll roads in my region.